# How to make MySQL automatically update value?

Tags: mysql

Hello,
Is it possible to tell MySQL to automatically update value of a given cell in a given interval of time?

E.g. I want to make MySQL update the value of a coloumn named "status" to "OFF" in every 60 seconds no matter what the original value is. This should happen automatically.

If possible, then how? Otherwise is there any other technique to do the same?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html

Comment: Solution (Mihai) is good, or you can write bash script and run cron.

Comment: you can do it with crontab, but i guess you need to use memcache or redis for this

Comment: <blackquote>"Implementing a Cron every 60 second or sooner can affect the performance of your server."</blackquote><br>
I found this type of statement while exploring about Cron in the web.

Comment: What @Mihai suggested is what you want to do. These other comments about crontab, memcache and redis are just to facepalm yourself, so try not to read them.

Answer (score 1):

I Think you should create the event

CREATE EVENT STATUSOFF
    ON SCHEDULE
      EVERY 1 MINUTE
        DO
update TABLE_NAME 
set status_off='OFF' ;

For more detail
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html